# How to decode strange HTML entities like &#8217 in wordpress?

Tags: php, android, wordpress, android-studio, webview

I'm developing WordPress Android app which loads post from my Wordpress site using JSON API. In JSON data its found some special characters `&#8230, &#8217, &#8230`. when android webview loads post it stops loading at this special characters. It doesn't loads the data after this characters. How to decode or skip/delete these characters in wordpress site or android app.

In one of the post contain `&#8217` after this character post is not visible. It has decoded only `&` but failed to decode `#8217`

I'm newbie in wordpress.

[JSON link for POST](http://www.marineeto.we.bs/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/41)

app post screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the output with the function **html_entity_decode**

```
$input = "Hello friends I&#8217;m sharing my experience...."
echo html_entity_decode($input);
```

outputs to: *Hello friends I’m sharing my experience....*